# Combinatorics - how many potential matches between n men and m women where n>m?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For example, for $4$ men $\{M_1...M_4\}$ and $3$ Women $\{W_1...W_3\}$, how many potential matches are there if the men go one by one proposing so one man ends up single? I know the answer is $73$ but cannot figure out how to get $73$.

Comment: How do you know that the answer is 73?

Comment: If we augment the list of women to include $\emptyset$ then you are just talking about the permutations on $4$ letters, so $4!=24$, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @wilkersmon From the solutions

Comment: @lulu not sure what you mean, we are trying to make matches not just the permutations of woemn

Comment: Well, I understand that.  But take a permutation on my augmented set.  Let's say $W_2\emptyset W_3W_1$.  Then that corresponds to the matches $(M_1,W_2), (M_2,\emptyset), (M_3,W_3), (M_4,W_1)$.  In other words, you just marry the men off to the permuted list in order.

Comment: @lulu 's argument seems to make sense. Perhaps the question asker left out some details?

Comment: If I have it wrong (certainly possible) please provide a "match list" that I exclude.  As $73-24=49$ there should be lots and lots of such examples.

Comment: Oh, I can get $73$, but I have to ignore what you wrote.  You get $73$ if you allow more than one man to stay single.

Comment: @lulu Oh that makes sense.  Yes I think it is implied that more than one man can stay single.  How do you get 73?

Comment: I just posted that calculation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to justify the answer $73$ one must re-write the problem and allow more than one man to stay single.  With this assumption, then let $C_i$ be the number of matches in which exactly $i$ men stay single.  Then, clearly, $$C_i=\binom 4i\times 3\times \cdots \times (3-(i-1))$$  We quickly see that the answer is then $$\sum_{i=1}^4 C_i=1+12+36+24=73$$

A similar calculation works for the general problem.  I don't know if there is a simple closed representation for the sum.